# Debugging Vue In chrome does not showing the original vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, laravel-7, chrome-debugging

I am new in Vue Js. I am developing a project in Laravel 7.* with Vue js.

**My Vue Project  Structure**

[image: directory structure]

**app.js File contains:**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.config.debug = true;
Vue.config.devtools = true;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.silent = false;

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';

import App from './App.vue';
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

import HomeComponent from './components/home/HomeComponent.vue';
import CreateComponent from './components/post/CreateComponent.vue';
import IndexComponent from './components/post/IndexComponent.vue';
import EditComponent from './components/post/EditComponent.vue';
import Notification from './components/Notification.vue';

const routes = [
    {
        name: 'home',
        path: '/',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        name: 'create',
        path: '/create',
        component: CreateComponent
    },
    {
        name: 'posts',
        path: '/posts',
        component: IndexComponent
    },
    {
        name: 'edit',
        path: '/edit/:id',
        component: EditComponent
    },
    {
        name: 'notify',
        path: '/notifications',
        component: Notification
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes});
const app = new Vue(Vue.util.extend({ router }, App)).$mount('#app');
```

**App.Vue File contains:**

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 p-0">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-info navbar-dark">
                    <div class="container">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <router-link to="/" class="nav-link">Home</router-link>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <router-link to="/create" class="nav-link">Create Post</router-link>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <router-link to="/posts" class="nav-link">Posts</router-link>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <router-link to="/notifications" class="nav-link">Notifications</router-link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <br/>
                    <!--                <transition name="fade">-->
                    <router-view></router-view>
                    <!--                </transition>-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
    .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
        transition: opacity .5s
    }

    .fade-enter, .fade-leave-active {
        opacity: 0
    }
</style>

<script type="text/babel">

    export default {}
</script>
```

**Webpack.mix file contains**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

let productionSourceMaps = false;
if ( ! mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.webpackConfig({
        devtool: 'eval-source-map'
    });
}

mix.sourceMaps(false, type = 'eval-source-map')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

**bootstrap.js file contains:**

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://dshop.test';
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
```

**HomeComponent.vue contains**

```
<template>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">Home Component</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    I'm the Home Component component.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now when I want to debug in Chrome the components don't showing the original components

[image]

Please help me! What configurations I have missed I can't find it.

**Regards**

Comment: Hope you installed the chrome extension Vue.js devtools so that you can debug Vue js applications .

Comment: I have already installed this extension but I want to debug the raw component from the console as I am new in vue I want to see how it works. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out? I am, and other developers are now having this issue with Chromium based browsers.  I opened a ticket with Chromium.

My Stackoverflow :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71387156/google-chome-99-devtools-source-tab-not-showing-vue-file-code-in-webpack-src-fo

Answer (score 2):

You cant see Vue component at this way. Install Vue dev tool plugin following this link:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd

Please note that in order to be able to see Vue dev tab in your chrome dev tools, you must have assets built as dev.
npm run dev or yarn watch etc.. If you run npm run production or yarn production, you will not have Vue tab since is not in development mode.

Comment: Thanks for editing answer and removing the link to dropbox image!

Answer (score 0):

Mixing CommonJS require and ES6 import did that bad behavior in a Vue3 + vite  + TypeScript Project. Using only ES6 import fix the problem in my case

Answer (score -2):

maybe try this extension when trying to debug Vue as it will show component structures, props and much more: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd

Comment: I have already installed this extension but I want to debug the raw component from the console as I am new in vue I want to see how it works. Thanks